# Why is it that when navigating between pages in React Native,the WillUnmount is called for page B,but the WillUnmount is not called for A?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to study [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/#react-navigation-lifecycle-events) from the documentation and have read this quote

> When going back from B to A, componentWillUnmount of B is called, but
> componentDidMount of A is not because A remained mounted the whole
> time.

Here is my question: Why was the `WillUnmount` called for the B component, but the `WillUnmount`  was not called for the A component?
I know it is for the performance, but what pages are the `WillUnmount` calls for, and which pages are the `WillUnmount` calls not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From above example, **A** is main screen and **B** is the second screen which was stacked over **A**, so think it like that **A** is still there and **B** is just over **A**, so when going back from **B** to **A**, **B** will be removed (unmounted) from that stack and hence ***WillUnmount*** of **B** will be called, but  **A** is not removed from stack and ***WillUnmount*** of **A** won't called until we exit the app or put screen **A** stacked over another screen and going back.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but I did not understand this point
" ...A won't called until we exit the app or put screen A stacked over another screen and going back."

can you explain more if possible, thank you

Comment: Here A is the root screen right, so A need to be unmounted to invoke WillUnmount and root screen will only unmounted when user exiting the app.
Another method is make another screen C as the root screen, then if we navigate to A and go back to C, then WillUnmount in A will invoke since A is removed from stack and C is the root stack.